# Facebook says my app is restricted, but when I click on appeal it says i don't have any restricted apps. How can i resolve?

Tags: facebook-apps, restriction

On my app page it gives me the message "We've restricted this app for violating the Meta Platform Terms and Developer Policies. Read more or appeal"

But when I click on appeal it says "None of your apps are restricted."

How can I resolve this error?

I was trying to remove the app restriction as it doesnt seem to be valid.

Comment: Try to contact their developer support. These are the only people that know what's going on with your account